# Simulating the feedback network in constant-current step-down converter

Tags: simulation, constant-current

I'm analysing a (real) step-down converter which gives a constant-current output and want help in how to simulate the feedback circuit, in the abstract.

The real circuit has an ST L5973AD ([datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l5973ad.pdf)), with feedback circuit from [ST Application Note 2823](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2823-current-source-for-led-driving-based-on-the-l5973ad-stmicroelectronics.pdf) Figure 5 with R1=2.8 kΩ, R6=1.4 kΩ, and Rsense of 0.68 Ω.  Per application note equation 4, it should give 298 mA with these values (measured values within tolerance.)  The internal error amplifier has a voltage ref of 1.235 V.

**How do we simulate this?** (In Circuit Lab or anything else.)  Surely a voltage-controlled voltage source is required.  But I don't see how how to choose the multiplier.  A crazy value of 10<sup>9</sup> seems to give plausible answers, but what is the correct way to do this?

[image: schematic]

---

*Edit Take 2 to add circuit in response to Andy Aka's answer: compensation left of LC*

[image: schematic]

*Andy's comment said this was wrong, because we see the compensation is left of the amplifier in the datasheet*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *A crazy value of \$10^9\$ seems to give plausible answers, but what is
> the correct way to do this?*

\$10^9\$ is high but \$10^3\$ wouldn't be a million miles off. If you look at the data sheet they say the error amplifier has a DC open-loop gain of 57 dB and that is a real-number gain of 708: -

[image]

So, you can use the VCVS with that gain but you would also need to add the inductor and output capacitor so that the stability of the circuit can be checked. And, of course, if the L and C are added it may become unstable hence you should add the compensation components shown in figure 5: -

[image]

Then, to implement the compensation circuit you'd need to model the error amplifier as a voltage to current converter as per this: -

[image]

The E/A in the diagram implies an error voltage to current converter and the output voltage develops across the compensation components shown earlier.

But, on the plus side, you don't need to model the switching parts if you just want to prove the dynamics of the control system. In other words it can be modelled as a linear regulator to get a decent fix on performance.

It all depends on how far you want to go.

All images in this answer are taken from links in the question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "you don't need to model the switching parts if you just want to prove the dynamics of the control system. In other words it can be modelled as a linear regulator to get a decent fix on performance" ... do you mean: add R5, C4, C5 and then simulate a high frequency switching of SW2?  Or something else?

Comment: @jonathanjo well I probably skipped a couple of points there. Yes it can be modelled as a linear system but I forgot to mention that the digital part will have gain. This is because it uses a comparator and conceivably that could have a massive equivalent linear gain. I've re-read the data sheet and sadly, it's lacking information on anything that might help there so, modelling might be a bit hit and miss. However, I would estimate that another gain stage be applied after the error amplifier that has a gain of 100......

Comment: ..... You would add R4, C4 and C5 to compensate for the massive phase change due to the LC components. You really do need to model LC if you want to understand the dynamic performance of the device.

Comment: I edited question to include what I think you're saying: "use the VCVS with that gain ... also add the inductor and output capacitor .. should add the compensation components".  Did I do it right?  But I don't know waht to do when you say "stability of the circuit can be checked."

Comment: The compensation is in the wrong place; look at the block diagram in my answer. It goes after the error to current amplifier. I'd probably also slip in an extra 100 gain stage after the VCVS output and before the inductor. Stability can be checked using a step input on the 1.235 volts (V2 in your diagram) and seeing how the output changes; a lot of ringing means it might go unstable @jonathanjo

Comment: Thanks again for futher comment.  At the risk of seeming dense, I've edited "Take 2", is that what you meant?

Comment: @jonathanjo the error amplifier is a current output type and hence the compensation components strongly affect the output voltage amplitude. Thereafter you add the gain of 100 VCVS stage before feeding the inductor. The data sheet does have details of the V/I value (from memory it's 2300 uS). That's siemens and not seconds!

Comment: @jonathanjo are we done with this question and answer now?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking, I was extremely grateful for your answer.

Comment: @jonathanjo if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.